# On submit function is not called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

At the end of the document I have:

```
<script>
    $("#submitEvent").click(function() {
        $("#eventForm").submit();
    });


    $(document).ready(function() {


    $('#eventForm').submit(function() {
        console.log("I am on submit");

    }); });
</script>
```

Now submitEvent is button which is not within a form so and the reason for having on .click event.

When button is pressed the form submit is triggered correctly:

```
<form id="eventForm" action="${contextPath}/dashboard/event/new"
                        method="post">
```

Now I expect another event to be fired when submit is fired which actually is ignored for some reason. Instead of console.log I am not surprisingly going to use ajax, but even console.log does not print anything so the event is not triggered..

Update, did as you suggested still nothing :-) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#submitEvent").click(function() {
        $("#eventForm").submit();
    });




    $('#eventForm').submit(function() {
        console.log("I am on submit");

    });


    });
```

Comment: Hm, so how can I check if ajax will be called. Try to change some value within dom ajax onSuccess?

Comment: As I said, put a breakpoint in the handler and see if it gets hit. Or if you want debugging from the 1990s, put in an `alert`. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it seems you are entirely correct I included code from Archer answer - it does print.

Comment: @ aubergine: Ah, good deal, just as well I posted it as an actual answer. :-) I learned something from this question, thanks: jQuery will call the submit handler, even though the equivalent JavaScript operation (calling `submit` on the `HTMLFormElement` programmatically) would not. Interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your reason for saying the form submit handler isn't being called is that you don't see the output in the console, remember that submitting a form completely tears down and replaces the page. You probably don't have time to see the log message before the console gets cleared.

---

In a comment, you said:

> Hm, so how can I check if ajax will be called.

You can check by setting a breakpoint on your `console.log` statement and seeing if the breakpoint gets hit. Or if you want to debug 1990's-style, use an `alert`.

But note that doing ajax from within a form submit handler, if the form's result will replace the page, is unreliable. (If the form's result *won't* replace the page, you're probably fine.) This is because ajax is asynchronous, meaning your submit handler could *start* it, but it wouldn't have time to finish before being cancelled by the teardown.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to move your code inside the ready function

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#submitEvent").click(function() {
          // run ajjax code here
       });

       $('#eventForm').submit(function(e) {
           e.preventDefault(); // stops the page from submiting
           console.log("I am on submit");
        }); 
     });
</script>
```

I updated the code, you don't need to submit the form. just run ajax on click.

Comment: The question says, just above the script: *"**At the end of the document** I have:"* (my emphasis).

Comment: Yeah I updated my question, and included on ready anyways - still nothing :-D

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#submitEvent").click(function() {
        $("#eventForm").submit();
    });

    $('#eventForm').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("I am on submit");
    });
});
```

It will stop the form submitting so you can see, for now, if the event is actually being triggered or not.

It may simply be that the form being submitted is reloading the page before you see the console output.

Comment: It actually prints after your update ! So @T.J. Crowder is correct?

Comment: Yes.  Just handle the submit however you intended to, now that you know your event handler is working :)